# HTTP cache invalidation

Tags: rest, http, caching, w3c, cache-control

I have a rest service that contains a cache, and sometimes I need to invalidate records in the cache - not from the client side, but on the server side, because the server produced new data. How do I do that? I just want to send some sort of HTTP message to the service that it should invalidate the cache entry. Should it be a "Get" with "Cache-Control" where I would not require to return a value, but just branch in the "Get" code to invalidate the entry? Or should it be a "Put" with an empty record? What is the best practice, and what's the rationale behind it?

Comment: a good blog http://www.jondavis.net/techblog/post/2013/08/10/A-Consistent-Approach-To-Client-Side-Cache-Invalidation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

when needs to cache invalidate it is actually not possible in client side. so data needs to be cached in server side only and a way to avoid data transfer if data is unchanged.

following could be done :
1. REST HEAD protocol serves this purpose, so basically you can write the impl which returns the status in REST HEAD call whether the data requested is changed or not, if changed then the client calls with GET protocol.